# Arrayindexoutofbound error in android ,how to resolve this during insertion in database?

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite

```
public void fetchcontent() throws IOException
            {
                    this.open();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    String csvFilename = "/mnt/sdcard/content.csv";
                   // ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList();
                    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
                    String row[] = null;
                    while((row = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                       st1 = row[0];
                       st2= row[1];
                       st3= row[2];
                       st4= row[3];
                       st5= row[4];
                       values.put(DatabaseHandler.Column1,st1);
                       values.put(DatabaseHandler.Column2,st2);
                       values.put(DatabaseHandler.Column3,st3);
                       values.put(DatabaseHandler.Column4,st4);
                       values.put(DatabaseHandler.Column5,st5);
                      database.insert(DatabaseHandler.Table_Name, null, values);
                       }
                    csvReader.close(); 
                MainActivity.tt1.append("\ncontent table created");
            }
```

this is my code for insertion in a table i have created,it gives java lang arrayindexoutofbound exception error how can i remove that please help my logcat shows this

```
02-21 16:27:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(12511): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.webdata/com.example.webdata.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
```

ok so as some of you mentioned i did removed the st4 and st5 statements and it worked fine for some time but now i am getting the same error for index 2 now what my array length is 2 but you all suggested previously it was 3,what is wrong here,am i missing something??/

Comment: obviously your row is of length 3, not 5

Comment: Its always obvious when you know the answer.. would the OP have posted if it was obvious to him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
st4= row[3];
```

Isn't working because the array row has a length of 3.

Most people are telling you to remove using the 3rd and 4th field entirely, but if you want to use default values, then you should add a check for this and insert empty data in the database if there is no corresponding data.

Something like this:

```
if (row[3] != null) {
    st3 = row[3];
} else {
    st3 = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This suggests your CSV file: `/mnt/sdcard/content.csv`, or at least one row in the CSV file, only has three columns.

See: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3` means only 3 items in the array and your trying tio access item at index 3 (max is 2)

Try it without:

```
st4= row[3];
st5= row[4];
```

and

```
values.put(DatabaseHandler.Column4,st4);
values.put(DatabaseHandler.Column5,st5);
```

Comment: my file has 5 columns as i can see that and as you mentioned i tried it as you mentioned above but it is still giving the same error can you explain me why

Comment: Can you post more of the stack trace, also debug through the code and post which line is breaking

Comment: Also, you need to make sure EVERY row contains all 5 columns in the CSV file, if not you need to check the length of the array before retrieving data from each column

Comment: now i am getting connection pool has been closed what does that mean?

Comment: This is a completely different error. It means there is a connection pool setup , probably for a database, but it is closed and you are trying to retrieve a connection from it. As I said a completely different question / error

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3*emphasized text*
```

The exception says the array contains 3 elements, but you are trying to acces 5 elements.